# Only System Account user can see the left navigation in SharePoint 2019 modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, modern-pages, left-navigation

Hello Community Members,

I am facing an issue with SharePoint 2019 modern pages. When I am logged in as System Account user, I can see the left navigation menu. But other than SA no one can see the left navigation menu (not even SCA user). I want to show the left navigation menu to all audience in my site. What am I missing? I have searched over the internet but didn't find relative answer about that.

**PS: when I switch to classic experience, it is showing me the left navigation to all users. The issue persist with modern page only.**

Comment: I could't reproduce your issue in my SharePoint 2019 modern site, please check other site collections to compare the result. Or change different browser then test again.Have you enabled publishing feature? If true, please deactive and activate again.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did that and it showed navigation in chrome but not showing in edge and IE. is there any chance to set any settings?

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache or open the site in Inprivate window to compare the result.